# Do you return an ObjectResult from your repository in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, repository-pattern

In an ASP.NET Core app I'm using `Task<IActionResult>` on the vast majority of my controller routes.  However, I'm also trying to use repositories.  The things like `NotFound()` or `Ok(ret)` that a controller would return aren't available in the repository.

I started off the repository by having those methods return a `Task<ObjectResult>` as that would pass through well to the controller, but then I quickly discovered that many of the "normal" ones I'd want don't exist.  For example, I had to make my own `CreateObjectResult`, `NoContentObjectResult`, etc...

Is there a better type to return so that my repository methods support easily returning either data or the appropriate error response?

Comment: You should not use ObjectResult or any other Controller Action Types in your repositories. Only return actual DTOs / POCOS from your repositories and handle what HttpStatus code results you want to return in the controller methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, repository should return Domain Model in case DDD is implemented. Domain Model itself mapped as Entity in that case.

If DDD is not implemented, it should return the Entity which is mapped.

Repository should concern only about database needs. It should not handle any other concerns like HTTP, Business Logic etc. Hence, it should not return `ObjectResult` or DTO or any other type that does not belong to data access. To learn more about the terms like DTO, Entity etc. please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46175582/5779732) answer.

> I'm also trying to use repositories. The things like `NotFound()` or `Ok(ret)` that a controller would return aren't available in the repository.

They shouldn't. Use additional logic to implement this outside the repository.;

> Is there a better type to return so that my repository methods support easily returning either data or the appropriate error response?

As said above, return the mapped entities. For errors, consider throwing exception from repository. Handle those in calling (controller) code.

Just in case you are using full ORM, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51781877/5779732) answer.